# Phonegap SyntaxError:Unexpected Token

Tags: android, cordova

So I'm running the phonegap build command

`phonegap build android`

But I'm getting a bunch of Unexpected Token.

[image]

I haven't done anything to any of those files so I'm wondering why it's throwing those errors.

Comment: Have you been able to build the project earlier? If so, have you added some plugins or done some other changes?

Comment: Nope I havent added any plugins. Just worked on the HTML and CSS.

Comment: Care to share the files you have modified?

Comment: If you have resolved the issue please share the answer. That might help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use build.phonegap.com to build once to verify that there is no problem with the hybrid code. If you can build it there then that indicates there is some issue with the setup like android sdk/version etc or plugins that are installed.